# String value for li-tag

Tags: html, html-lists

The documentation (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_value.asp) says, that a value for a li element must be numeric. Why should it be wrong to use a string instead of a number, if you need the value for saving a f.E. locale like 'US', 'EN' etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

The value of a list element is the number that the list starts from in an ordered list. Take a look:

4. starts from 4
5. goes to 5
6. yes, this is a real list

If you want to have a locale associated with it, use the `lang` attribute.

Text for the `<li>` goes inside the tag as with any other.

Also, please read http://www.w3fools.com/ before looking at that documentation again, it will save you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

The value is to set the numbering for an ordered list. It is not a text label.